# Using Relational Controls, how do you do a "soft" delete

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

In the relational controls sample db (xpagesjdbc.nsf) there is an example called JDBC_RowSetDatasource.  This uses a view panel and has the check box turned on in the view panel to allow the user to select a document.  Then there is a button to delete the selected docs using a simple action, delete selected documents.  This deletes the document but until the button with the code that has jdbcData1.acceptChanges() is pressed the changes are not committed and the row shows as to be deleted (first icon column with the isRowDeleted() call to determine the icon).

I am working on a similar situation but with a repeat control.  I can delete the row with @jdbcDelete but that is immediate. Looking at the data it shows the row is gone from the data even before acceptChanges() is called.

Since I can't use the simple action to delete selected documents (no view panel) what is the Java equivalent to delete the row in a similar manner?  I have tried deleteRow() on both the variable for the data set and for the row but get an error in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Howard, the simple action just memorizes the primary keys of the records as to be deleted. If you want to simulate that you need to take a similar approach (using a ViewScope variable or bean) to keep track of your "deleted" records and a method that executes the actual deletion.
Smells like a case for a bean

Comment: How would you reference the row and then what method would you call to do a "soft" delete like the simple action did in the example XPage I referenced? A @jdbcDelete deletes the record immediately. thanks, Howard

Comment: There is no universal method. It only will work if the records have a primary key. You memorize the the primary key and when ready to execute run a @jdbcDelete against them.

Comment: A "true" soft delete like Notes is not in the nature of SQL. You would need to change the table to include a binary field "isDeleted" that you would want to set, so you can get the records back.

Comment: One idea: check if a soft deleted Notes document that is DECT to a RDBMS deletes the RDBMS record (and recreates it when restored)? Never tried it, would be interesting to find out

Comment: Stephan, see the demo I mentioned above.  The delete with the simple actions is not committed until the button with acceptChanges() is pressed. thanks, Howard

Comment: But it isn't a soft delete. It is just select documents and delete them in bulk. Once they are gone you can't recall them. So not a soft delete at all.